# Elasticsearch 5 (Searchkick) Aggregation Bucket Averages

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

We have an ES index holding scores given for different products. What we're trying to do is aggregate on product names and then get the average scores for each of product name 'buckets'. Currently the default aggregation functionality only gives us the counts for each bucket - is it possible to extend this to giving us average score per product name?

We've looked at pipeline aggregations but the documentation is pretty dense and doesn't seem to quite match what we're trying to do.

Here's where we've got to:

```
{
  "aggs"=>{
    "prods"=>{
      "terms"=>{
        "field"=>"product_name"
        }, 
        "aggs"=>{
          "avgscore"=>{
            "avg"=>{
              "field"=>"score"
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Either this is wrong, or could it be that there's something in how searckick compiles its ES queries that is breaking things?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please show your query that you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Think this is the pipeline aggregation you want...

```
POST /_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
     "product_count" : {
        "terms" : {
        "field" : "product"
        },
        "aggs": {
          "total_score": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "score"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg_score": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "product_count>total_score" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully I have that the right way round, if not - switch the first two buckets.